# Starting and Stopping boolean() function

Tags: java, boolean, processing

I'm attemping to use this code from http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/7050 to make countries formed using the letters from the name of whatever the country is. But I want to make it so once the user presses the right arrow key, the process will start over again, but instead, created a new country and use the letters of that country. I'm a little stuck- what I have makes it so when you press the right arrow key, it begins to make the next country from where ever the previous function left off. Is there a way to make it so it just starts over instead?

```
    PFont font;
String fontpath = "ArialMT-200.vlw";
int fontstart = 300;
int fontend = 8;
float fontsize = fontstart;
float fontsizedecrease = 0.97;
PImage bg;
PImage australia;
String country1 = "australia.jpg";
String country2 = "austria.jpg";
String letters = "Australia";
char[] chars = new char[52];
int nchars = 0;
int iterations = 500;
int c = 0;
PGraphics letter,lettersquare,drawing;


void setup(){
  //initialize the sketch
  size(900,600);
  //background(255);
  //initialize the font
  //font = loadFont(fontpath);
  ///*
  for(int i=0;i<letters.length();i++){
    boolean found = false;
    char lc = letters.charAt(i);
    for(int j=0;j<nchars;j++){
      if(chars[j]==lc){
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!found) chars[nchars++] = lc;
  }
  chars = (char[]) subset(chars,0,nchars);
  font = createFont("Arial",200,true,chars);
  //*/
  textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
  //load the image that will be filled with letters
  australia = loadImage(country1);
    austria = loadImage(country2);
    //france = loadImage(country3);
     //guatemala = loadImage(country4);
     // italy = loadImage(country5);
      // japan = loadImage(country6);
  bg = loadImage("background.jpg");
  //posterize the image
  australia.filter(THRESHOLD,0.4);
  australia.filter(BLUR,3);
  australia.filter(THRESHOLD,0.6);

 austria.filter(THRESHOLD,0.4);
  austria.filter(BLUR,3);
  austria.filter(THRESHOLD,0.6);
  //initialize the drawing buffers
  letter = createGraphics((int)fontsize,(int)fontsize,JAVA2D);
  lettersquare = createGraphics((int)fontsize,(int)fontsize,P2D);
  drawing = createGraphics(width,height,JAVA2D);
  drawing.beginDraw();
  drawing.background(255);
  // THIS STUPID THING NEEDS TO GO HERE!!!!
  drawing.image(bg,0,0);
  drawing.endDraw();

}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  if(floor(fontsize)>fontend&&c<letters.length()-1){
    if(!letterfit()){
      fontsize *= fontsizedecrease;
    }else{
      c++;
      if(c==11){
        fontsize *= 0.75;
      }
    }
    tint(255);
    image(drawing,0,0);
    if(mousePressed){
      tint(255,100);
      image(australia,0,0);
    }
  }else{
    tint(255);
    image(drawing,0,0);
    println(c+" "+letters.length());
    /*
    save("mlk-"+hour()+""+minute()+""+second()+".tif");
    exit();
    */
    noLoop();
  }
}     
boolean letterfit(){
  letter.beginDraw();
  letter.background(255,0);
  letter.fill(0);
  letter.textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
  letter.translate(fontsize/2,fontsize/2);
  letter.rotate(random(TWO_PI));
  letter.scale(fontsize/fontstart);
  letter.textFont(font);
  letter.smooth();
  letter.text(letters.charAt(c),0,0);
  letter.endDraw();
  lettersquare.beginDraw();
  lettersquare.background(255);
  lettersquare.image(letter,0,0);
  lettersquare.filter(ERODE);
  lettersquare.filter(ERODE);
  lettersquare.endDraw();
  for(int i=0;i<iterations;i++){
    int x = floor(random(width-fontsize));
    int y = floor(random(height-fontsize));
    boolean fits = true;
    for(int dx=0;dx<fontsize&&fits;dx++){
      for(int dy=0;dy<fontsize&&fits;dy++){
        if(brightness(australia.get(x+dx,y+dy))>127){
          fits = false;
          break;
        }
        if(brightness(lettersquare.get(dx,dy))<127){
          if(brightness(drawing.get(x+dx,y+dy))<127){
            fits = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

   if (keyCode == RIGHT) {

    for(int dx=0;dx<fontsize&&fits;dx++){
      for(int dy=0;dy<fontsize&&fits;dy++){
        if(brightness(austria.get(x+dx,y+dy))>127){
          fits = false;
          break;
        }
        if(brightness(lettersquare.get(dx,dy))<127){
          if(brightness(drawing.get(x+dx,y+dy))<127){
            fits = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if(fits){
      drawing.beginDraw();
      drawing.image(letter,x,y);
      drawing.endDraw();
      return true;
    }
  }

    if(fits){
      drawing.beginDraw();
      drawing.image(letter,x,y);
      drawing.endDraw();
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Does not look like you have provided enough code to see the full error.

Comment: Agreed, please post the rest of your pde. I want to say that you shouldn't be triggering your restart in the middle of letterfit() function, and that you should place it elsewhere, but can't know or give details without the rest of the code.

Comment: I added some more code in, if i added to much I'm sorry! And this code only works with ps 1.x versions due to the 1217 issue.